# Simple XML @ElementMap unable to satisfy key attribute

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I'm trying to deserialise with Simple XML 2.6.2 using the @ElementMap annotation to build a map containing an element's attribute as the key and the element itself as the value.

The XML looks like this:

```
<ProcessConfiguration id="4020">
  <EquipmentConfigurations>
    <EquipmentConfiguration id="5020">
      <address>foo</address>
    </EquipmentConfiguration>
  </EquipmentConfigurations>
</ProcessConfiguration>
```

The annotated classes look like this:

```
@Root
class ProcessConfiguration {

  @Attribute
  Long id;

  @ElementMap(name = "EquipmentConfigurations", key="id", attribute = true)
  Map<Long, EquipmentConfiguration> equipmentConfigurations = new HashMap<>();
}
```

EquipmentConfiguration.java

```
@Root
class EquipmentConfiguration {

  @Attribute
  Long id;

  @Element
  String address;
}
```

As you can see, the `equipmentConfigurations` map should contain the `EquipmentConfiguration` ID as the map key, and the `EquipmentConfiguration` as the map value.

But when I try to deserialise, the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(required=true, empty=, name=) on field 'id' java.lang.Long EquipmentConfiguration.id for class EquipmentConfiguration at line 1
```

I've tried various things with the @ElementMap annotation, but without success.

I'm pretty stuck here, as I don't see how Simple isn't finding the `id` attribute. Are there any Simple wizards out there who can help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class structure states that you need a xml file like below. As the error states, a key is missing for the Map entry. It is not the same as id of Equipment configuration.

```
    <ProcessConfiguration id="4020">
      <EquipmentConfigurations class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry id="56789">
            <EquipmentConfiguration id="5020">
              <address>foo</address>
            </EquipmentConfiguration>
        </entry>
      </EquipmentConfigurations>
    </ProcessConfiguration>
```

Edit: If you can't change the structure of XML, you can change your `ProcessConfiguration` class as below:

```
  @Root
  static class ProcessConfiguration {

    @Attribute
    Long id;

    @ElementList(name = "EquipmentConfigurations")
    List<EquipmentConfiguration> equipmentConfigurations = new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, but unfortunately I am not able to change the XML structure (nor am I able to change any of the Java data structures).

Comment: The example you have provided works for a `ElementList` not a `ElementMap`, you could replace `ElementMap` code line with: `@ElementList(name = "EquipmentConfigurations")`

Comment: You're right, that works. I actually added a method with the `@Commit` annotation to manually populate the HashMap from the List at the end of the deserialisation. Thanks!